# Showing API response after calling it

Tags: typescript, react-native, api

I am calling an api end point that should render some information. I am calling the API but need an event to trigger it. I am triggering that event with a `setTimeout` function.

Although nothing is rendering, I am getting an error of `Cannot read property state of undefined`

This is the code:

```
const TermsAndCond = () => {
  const [terms] = useState('');
  const callTerms = () => {
    Terms({ terms: terms })
      .then((resp: any) => {
        if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            ({ callTerms: resp });
          }, 1000);
        }
        console.log('Data time', resp);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Terms & Conditions</Text>
        <Button title='hellow' onPress={callTerms} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please provide more info about the error. Apparently you're using functional component that are stateless components and you're getting error because of state. Can you provide more info about the API you're using?

Comment: That is the exact problem I am having. How do I render the data into a state and call it? I am calling an API that is a text rich HTML doc

Comment: What is `Terms({ terms: terms })`? See https://blog.bitsrc.io/fetching-data-in-react-using-hooks-c6fdd71cb24a#:~:text=The%20useEffect%20will%20make%20a,the%20DOM%20with%20the%20data.

Comment: @ShivamJha this is exactly what I need. Will add the answer shortly